# IDLEX unistall with pip command(or pip 3)

Tags: python, pip, installation

Is it possible to uninstall IDLEX using pip?
http://idlex.sourceforge.net/
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install it with `pip`? If so, did you try `pip uninstall idlex`??

Comment: Thanks yes,running python 3.6 no i did not yet.

Comment: So, you installed it with `pip install idlex` and tried to uninstall it with `pip uninstall idlex`?

Comment: Everything ok,with pip uninstall,idlex is removed.thanks!